# Hiding a segemented control in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Hi all i have a segmented control in my app.
I want to hide that control on a specific condition.
i tried to hide as we do it for a normal button.
Create an outlet and using set Hidden property.But there is no such property for a segmented control
So is there a way by which we can hide a segmented control ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can put the segment in a view ,whenever you want to hide, hide the view.

Comment: Use [segment setHidden:YES]; when you want to hide segment

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setHidden` property for `NSSegmentedControl` like that below:-

```
(if someCondition)?[self.segCntrl setHidden:NO]:[self.segCntrl setHidden:YES];
```

Note:- `NSSegmentedControl` and `NSButton` both inherited from `NSControl` which further inherited from `NSView`. So there is property of `NSView` if you look into the class of `NSView.h` inside `Appkit Framework`.

Comment: Nice explanation for inheritance. +1

Answer (score 0):

Creating NSSegmentedControl from code or IB doesn't affect any of the properties. The properties usage is same in both case.

Make sure you have connected the segmentControlInstance from InterfaceBuilder to the related pointer in code.

UIButton and UISegmentedControl both inherit from UIControl which in tern is inherited from UIView. The UIView has setHidden method which definitely works for the instances of UIButton & UISegmentedControl.

Suppose you have your Segment Control visible.

[segCtrl setHidden:NO];

if (specific condition) 
    [segCtrl setHidden:YES];

This will certainly work in normal cases.